# i have issue with migrations

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, migration

i have issue with migration
my problem is i have class name Db context but when i start to enable migration nuget say:
 No context type was found in the assembly 'MyCms.DataLayer 
also DataLayer is my deafualt project
also i inject conection string in startup with appsettings.json

```
public class MyCmsDbContext : DbContext
    {
        public MyCmsDbContext(DbContextOptions<MyCmsDbContext> options) : base(options)
        {

        }


        public DbSet<PageGroup> PageGroups { get; set; }
        public DbSet<Page> Pages { get; set; }
```

acctuly i found it.the problem was  with nuget package 
i forgot to inistall entityframwork.tools

Comment: Do you mean that DataLayer is the only layer in your project?

Comment: with my web i have 5 layer

Comment: Do it like the solution that I mention, --project is a layer that contains context , and --startup-project is your main project like: web app , web api , ...

Comment: yes bro DataLayer have Context class

Answer (score 0):

if you have multiple layers and data layer is distinct from startup project(UI) you can use this command :

```
dotnet ef migrations add InitialMigration --project "MyCms.DataLayer" --startup-project "MyCms.WebUI"
```

edit startup configuration :

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationContext>(option =>
            option.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Default"),
            assembly => assembly.MigrationsAssembly(typeof(ApplicationContext).Assembly.FullName)));
```

Comment: Can you also attach add database configuration section in startup.cs ?

Comment: i use iconfiguration cunstractor then i use AddDbContext with lambda expersion............options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("MyCmsDbContext")) ); other side of project in appsetting i set conection string

Comment: thank you bro but i think the issue is not the connection string or depenenci i do your cod and still say No context type was found in the assembly 'MyCms.DataLayer'.